# content-security-policy allows plain functions, but not library-type functions - why?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

If I visit `google.com` and run the raw script from https://github.com/ded/qwery/blob/master/src/qwery.js I can then use that library in the Chrome Developer Tools.

However, if I visit e.g. oculus.com, this fails. If I understand correctly, this is because a website can set a `content-security-policy` in the headers.

**Now what I don't understand is that I can run or inject the "actual code within" from the library without issues. If I run an individual function from that js file, I can execute it just fine.**

What is the "structure" of the JS that makes `content-security-policy` block this exactly? I was able to reproduce this behavior with a minimal example for easier understanding. I can run the following without issues on any website:

```
function turnBlue() {
    console.log("Turning blue")
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

> turnBlue() // works on both `google.com` and `oculus.com`. Prints and turns blue
```

Now if I put my `turnBlue()` in this "library structure" based on the linked library, it will work on `google.com` but not on `oculus.com`:

```
(function(name, context, definition) {
    if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports)
        module.exports = definition()
    else if (typeof define == 'function' && define.amd)
        define(definition)
    else
        context[name] = definition()
}
)('turnBlue', this, function() {

    function turnBlue() {
        console.log("Turning blue")
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }

    return turnBlue
}, this);

> turnBlue() // oculus.com: Uncaught ReferenceError: turnBlue is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1
```

If I put things in a Chrome Extension background script it runs fine but this is not my goal.

I can't find any information as to why the "library structure" breaks things on some websites so I'd like to know why that happens. I'd like to know this in order to be able to "re-write" the structure of libraries in order to be able to run them without being restricted on some websites.

Comment: Well your "library structure" doesn't create a global `turnBlue` variable, so why would you expect to be able to access it from the console?

Comment: Your "library structure" has some `if` conditions at the very top that are changing what it does. Have you debugged them to find whether `module` or `define` are available on some of the pages where you tried to run this?

Comment: Most likely google has no existing module structure you go to the third branch of your `if` and assign to global scope. Occulus does so your function is assigned to `window.module` and is not available in global scope